# Is exactly one of $a, a + b^n, ..., a + b^{p - 1}$ divisible by $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the following structure over $\mathbb{N_0}$: $2, 2 + 3^n, 2 + 3^{n + 1}, ..., 2 + 3^{n + 3}$. Here we have five numbers and it's not hard to prove that exactly one if them is divisible by $5$.

What about general result?
Consider a general structure over $\mathbb{N_0}$: $a, b, p \in \mathbb{N}$):

$a, a + b^n, a + b^{n + 1}, ..., a + b^{n + p - 2}.$ Of course, assume $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p.$

My hypothesis is that exactly one of $a + b^i, i = n, n + 1, ..., n + p - 2$ is divisible by $p$, but does this property holds for any $p, b$? Or maybe just if $(b, p) = 1$ or one of them (or both?) is a prime? How to prove this?

Comment: $3$ is a primitive root $\pmod 5$, that's what's going on here.  Try $4$ instead of $3$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't studied about primitive roots yet, can you please be more concrete?

Comment: Sure.  Every number prime to $5$ is congruent to one of $3, 3^2, 3^3, 3^4\pmod 5$  That's what "primitive root" means.  If you want to stick with $b=3$, try $p=11$ instead.  This time we get $3^5\equiv 1 \pmod {11}$, so you either miss a value or you get it twice in your list.

Comment: To stress:  you don't need to know what a primitive root is to check the counterexamples I have proposed.  For the first one, I suggest taking $b=4, p=5, n=1$.  For the second, I propose $b=3, p=11, n=1$.

Comment: One intermezzo: how to prove $0, a^n, a^{n + 1}, ..., a^{n + b - 2}$ is complete residue system $\text{mod} \ b$ for any natural $a, b$ such that $(a, b) = 1$?

Comment: Again, it's not true in general.  The same counterexamples apply.  Try $a=3, b=11, n=1$.  Then your list is $\{0,3,9,5,4,1,3,9,5,4,1\}\pmod {11}$.

Comment: The Primitive Root Theorem I alluded too earlier says that, for any prime $p$, there is a residue $g$ such that $\{1, g, g^2, \cdots, g^{p-1}\}$ is a complete list of non-zero residues $\pmod p$.  But this is not true for all $g$ nor is it true if you replace $p$ by a general composite (though there are composites for which it is true).

Comment: Aha... I understand now that part. So, in the last example, $b$ has to be *primitive root* of $a$?

Comment: Well, $a$ has to be a primitive root for $b$.  Thus $3$ is a primitive root for $5$ but not for $11$.

Comment: So condition $a$ has ti be primitive root of $b$ a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113766/discussion-between-1b3b-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I can't talk further right now.  Good luck!

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement that exactly one of $\{a+s\colon s\in S\}$ is a multiple of $p$ for every $a$ given a set $S$ of size $p$ is equivalent to $S$ having one element with every remainder modulo $p$. (For an element $s\in S$ of remainder $r$, the number $a+s$ will be a multiple of $p$ for every $a\equiv -r\bmod p$, and this covers every $a$ exactly once as you vary $r$.)

Your set $S$ consists of $b^n$ times every element of $\{0,1,b,b^2,\dots,b^{p-2}\}$. If $b$ is a multiple of $p$ this clearly isn't going to work, so $S$ consisting of all residues modulo $p$ is the same as $\{0,1,b,b^2,\dots,b^{p-2}\}$ consisting of all residues modulo $p$. It is clear that this set has only one zero mod $p$, so it's the same as powers of $b$ reaching every nonzero value modulo $p$.

Unfortunately given a pair $(b,p)$ it isn't obvious whether it satisfies this property. However, what you do know is that $b^k$ can't be $1$ modulo $p$ for any $1\leq k\leq p-2$.  However, by the pigeonhole principle, the numbers $\{b^0,b^1,\dots,b^{p-1}\}$, as there are $p$ of them and none are $0$ modulo $p$, must contain some two elements that are equivalent modulo $p$. If $b^i\equiv b^j\bmod p$, then $b^{i-j}\equiv 1$, and the only way for this to happen while keeping all residues from $b^0$ to $b^{p-2}$ distinct is if $b^{p-1}=1\bmod p$ but no $b^k$ with $0<k<p-1$ is. In fact, $b^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ for all $b$ (this is Fermat's little theorem), but you can show via an extension of this pigeonhole argument that the $b$ that satisfy your condition are exactly those for which $p-1$ is the minimal such exponent. As noted in the comments, these are called [primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n), and their existence for every prime $p$ is a rather important theorem of number theory.

Comment: It's late so I'll read it tomorrow. It seems promising, thank you so much!